# Cropping a photo

Tags: css, crop

I have a photo that is about 240px x 366 px. My width is just how I would like it. I need to include only the middle 100 px vertically so essentially I will have the middle of the photo shown vertically across the entire width.

This is the code I have so far:

```
var img = '<img title="' + title + '" alt="' + title + '" class="blog-image-ind" src="' + imgSrc + '" width="240" style="float:left;" />'
```

Comment: Open any image editor, crop image and upload it to site, why are you trying to crop it by css (it is possible), but why users should download bigger image instead of cropped one?

Comment: I use the full image on a different part of the page and I am trying to avoid having to upload 2 pictures.

Comment: then read about css clip property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the `img` in a `div`, set that `div` to `overflow: hidden` and `height: 100px`, and the `img` to `margin-top: -133px`

```
<div id="cropimage">
    <img src="whatever" alt="whatever">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cropimage { overflow: hidden; height: 100px }
#cropimage img { width: 240px; height: 366px; margin-top: -133px }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9L9MJ/

(no actual image)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would do it if the height of the picture changed? It would be something along the lines of a percentage.

Comment: If you know its size, then the margin-top is simply `((height-100)/2)+'px'` (you would need to do that in the `style` of the `img` rather than a class). Otherwise you might be able to use a `margin-top: -50%` coupled with a `padding-top: 50px`, let me try that.